# how could select more than 14 column

Tags: mysql-5.6

Not able to select morethan 14 columns in the list

please find the link for reference,

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bb7a66/3

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_staff_details
    (`name` varchar(45), `FK_int_emp_id` int, `branch` varchar(45));



INSERT INTO tbl_staff_details
    (`name`, `FK_int_emp_id`, `branch`)
VALUES
    ('Arun', 6004, 'CORPORATE OFFICE'),
    ('Shyam', 6009, 'CORPORATE OFFICE'),
    ('Irshad', 5001, 'KANNUR');


CREATE TABLE tbl_absentees
    (`Date` datetime, `Status` varchar(12), `FK_int_emp_id` int, `branch` varchar(45));


INSERT INTO tbl_absentees
    (`Date`, `Status`, `FK_int_emp_id`, `branch`)
VALUES
    ('2015-12-01 00:00:00', 'EL', 6004, 'CORPORATE OFFICE'),
    ('2015-12-01 00:00:00', 'CL', 6009, 'CORPORATE OFFICE'),
    ('2015-12-02 00:00:00', 'SL', 6004, 'CORPORATE OFFICE'),
    ('2015-12-03 00:00:00', 'LOP', 6004, 'CORPORATE OFFICE'),
    ('2015-12-04 00:00:00', 'EL', 6009, 'CORPORATE OFFICE'),
    ('2015-12-05 00:00:00', 'COMP OFF', 6004, 'CORPORATE OFFICE'),
    ('2015-12-05 00:00:00', 'LOP', 5001, 'KANNUR');


CREATE TABLE tb_calendar
    (`Date` datetime);



INSERT INTO tb_calendar
    (`Date`)
VALUES
    ('2015-12-01 00:00:00'),
    ('2015-12-02 00:00:00'),
    ('2015-12-03 00:00:00'),
    ('2015-12-04 00:00:00'),
    ('2015-12-05 00:00:00'),
    ('2015-12-06 00:00:00'),
    ('2015-12-07 00:00:00'),
    ('2015-12-08 00:00:00'),
    ('2015-12-09 00:00:00'),
    ('2015-12-10 00:00:00');
```

Comment: Welcome to the forum. In future, could you please make use of the formatting tools above the question edit window - they help make your question more legible and will help  you get better answers. I ran the SQLFiddle - what appears to be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You are hitting the limit on the `GROUP_CONCAT()` results length - [group_concat_max_len](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len) as can be seen in http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bb7a66/16

You can raise it temporarily for your query:

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 10240;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bb7a66/19